# Is tap water in Athens safe to drink?

Tags: greece, tap-water, athens

1. [Tripadvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g189400-i194-k6209067-Is_tap_water_safe_to_drink_in_Athens-Athens_Attica.html) says that is okay to drink.
2. The EU Parliament [letter](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/E-6-2008-3936-ASW_EL.html?redirect) reported the absence of asbestos pipes in Greece.

I wonder does Athens have similar to Tallinn [initiative](https://%20https://news.err.ee/1608233880/tallinn-calling-on-companies-to-offer-tap-water-to-clients) of eco-friendly catering facilities to offer their customers tap water instead of bottled water?

Much appreciate official data sources if possible.

Thank you

Comment: Asbestos cement pipes for carrying water aren't really a health risk.  Asbestos is dangerous if it gets into your lungs (as is water...)

Comment: Tap water is safe to drink all over the EU and many other European countries. It might taste awfully (especially on mediterranean islands) but is safe.

Comment: Second @Midavalo. Asbestos in water is not a concern any more than asbestos in undisturbed tiles is. Asbestos is only a concern when it is airborne and can be inhaled into the lungs.

Comment: How is this travel related?

Comment: This is travel related because visitors to an area need to ask about it while people living in the area already know and will be warned about changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's technically safe to drink, specially in Athens. However, depending where you live it might have more chlorine (and chlorine taste) than you are used to. Which is just a taste problem, not a health one.
Contrary to what was said in the comments there are some Greek islands where drinking tap water is not recommended.
Also Greece have fairly cheap bottled water, and in restaurants water is always the cheapest item in the menu.

Comment: There are islands where the tap water reportedly tastes very bad, coming from deep wells, with high mineral content including sodium. But I've never seen warnings on health grounds, only on taste. When you say "not recommended" what do you actually mean?

Comment: It's about this report: https://www.oecd.org/environment/resources/financing-water-supply-sanitation-and-flood-protection-country-fact-sheet-greece.pdf and also anecdotal evidence (not real evidence). To be honest it doesn't seem like it's unhealthy to drink, but it doesn't show much certainty either.